# Concrete5 - PHP: Cannot get desired sort order from array using usort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, concrete5, usort

So I'm trying to alphabetically order my article titles in concrete5, however, they always show the default order.  I've attempted different methods of sorting before finding [this documentation](https://documentation.concrete5.org/tutorials/get-topic-node-display-order) but it still doesn't seem to work.  I'm newer to the concept of sorting something like this.

If someone could clarify how usort works --I was a bit confused by the php documentation I read.  How is it making a comparison between $a and $b?  I imagine this might not even be the way to go since I want its sort order to be alphabetical.

Any wisdom would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
 <?php
      function orderNode($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a->value, $b->value);
      }
      usort($artCategoryOptions, "orderNode");
      ?>

      <?php if($urlparam == '?category=Articles' || strpos($urlparam, '?article_category') !== false) {?>
      <h3>ARTICLE CATEGORIES</h3>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked space-bottom">
        <?php foreach ($artCategoryOptions as $cat) { ?>
          <li class="<?php if ($artCategoriesFilter == $cat->value) echo 'active'; ?>">
            <a href="/newsroom/?article_category=<?php echo $cat->value ?>">
              <strong><?php echo $cat->value ?></strong>
            </a>
          </li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
      <?php } ?>
```

The vardump of $artCategoryOptions --which is what I'm trying to sort is:

```
object(SelectAttributeTypeOptionList)#327 (2) 
{ ["options":"Concrete5_Model_SelectAttributeTypeOptionList":private]=> array(7) 
    { [0]=> object(SelectAttributeTypeOption)#328 (6) 
        { 
            ["error"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["ID"]=> string(2) "49" 
            ["value"]=> string(10) "Employment" 
            ["th"]=> object(TextHelper)#23 (0) { } 
            ["displayOrder"]=> int(0) 
            "usageCount"]=> string(1) "6" 
        }
    [1]=> object(SelectAttributeTypeOption)#329 (6) 
        { 
            ["error"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["ID"]=> string(2) "52" 
            ["value"]=> string(18) "Products Liability" 
            ["th"]=> object(TextHelper)#23 (0) { } 
            ["displayOrder"]=> int(1) 
            ["usageCount"]=> string(1) "3" 
        } 
    [2]=> object(SelectAttributeTypeOption)#330 (6)
        { 
            ["error"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["ID"]=> string(2) "50" 
            ["value"]=> string(10) "Litigation" 
            ["th"]=> object(TextHelper)#23 (0) { } 
            ["displayOrder"]=> int(2) 
            ["usageCount"]=> string(1) "3" 
        } 
    [3]=> object(SelectAttributeTypeOption)#331 (6)
         { 
             ["error"]=> string(0) "" 
             ["ID"]=> string(2) "48" 
             ["value"]=> string(12) "Construction" 
             ["th"]=> object(TextHelper)#23 (0) { } 
             ["displayOrder"]=> int(3) 
             ["usageCount"]=> string(1) "2" 
         } 
    [4]=> object(SelectAttributeTypeOption)#332 (6) 
         { 
             ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["ID"]=> string(2) "53" 
             ["value"]=> string(11) "Health Care" 
             ["th"]=> object(TextHelper)#23 (0) { } 
             ["displayOrder"]=> int(4) 
             ["usageCount"]=> string(1) "2" 
         } 
    [5]=> object(SelectAttributeTypeOption)#333 (6) 
         { 
             ["error"]=> string(0) "" 
             ["ID"]=> string(2) "54" 
             ["value"]=> string(11) "Real Estate" 
             ["th"]=> object(TextHelper)#23 (0) { } 
             ["displayOrder"]=> int(5) 
             ["usageCount"]=> string(1) "1" 
         } 
    [6]=> object(SelectAttributeTypeOption)#334 (6) 
         { 
             ["error"]=> string(0) "" 
             ["ID"]=> string(2) "55" 
             ["value"]=> string(17) "Creditor's Rights" 
             ["th"]=> object(TextHelper)#23 (0) { } 
             ["displayOrder"]=> int(6) 
             ["usageCount"]=> string(1) "1" } 
         } 
     ["error"]=> string(0) "" 
 }
```

Comment: Your approach looks fine, but $artCategoryOptions is an object not an array. A quick hack to turn it into an array should be (insert before your code): `$acoCopy=$artCategoryOptions;unset($artCategoryOptions);foreach($acoCopy as $v) $artCategoryOptions[] = $v;`. But obviously using the functions Concrete5 provides is preverable. Let's hope somebody else comes along.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that.  Yes, in-fact that does allow me to sort it as desired.  So you've essentially copied the data into $acoCopy and rebuilt the array after unsetting it with the values in that copy?  Clever.  It's interesting that the documentation wasn't clear on that.  I suppose attributes that are select menus in the backend could be treated differently (as objects rather than an array)...  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're right. Don't sweat missing it. Since the class implements traversable many array-like things (like foreach) work just like with arrays, but others don't. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you go into the Dashboard and change the "Option Order" for the attribute to "Alphabetical" it would return them in the order you want without you having to re-sort them.